# Namespaces in XML documents in eXist-db returns empty API calls

Tags: xml, rest, xml-namespaces, exist-db, xquery-3.1

I have an eXist-db with a collection of XML documents. All documents have a namespace in the top node which looks like this

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" version="5.0" xml:id="No-MM_N0001-01">
```

When I try to query the documents for information in //div/p from the REST API I get an empty response:

```
Request:
/data?_query=%2F%2Fdiv%2Fp

Response:
<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist" exist:hits="0" exist:start="1" exist:count="0" exist:compilation-time="3" exist:execution-time="3"/>
```

But when I edit one of the documents, removing the xmlns, I get data from the document that I have edited.

```
Request:
/data?_query=%2F%2Fdiv%2Fp

Response:
<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist" exist:hits="2" exist:start="1" exist:count="2" exist:compilation-time="1" exist:execution-time="1">
<p>
Jeg fik ikke sove –
<del rend="overstrike">j</del>
så den
<lb/>
lille striben mellem ridauerne lysne
<lb/>
mere og mere –
<del rend="overwritten">v</del>
jeg vendte mig hed
<lb/>
i sengen – Det var
<del rend="overstrike">jo</del>
så tydeli –
```

So, the question is, how can I query the XML documents in my collection without editing out the namespace in all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options. Just a few off the top of my head:

1. You could send the XPath `//*:div/*:p`
   This basically uses a wildcard prefix, which means "any namespace".
2. Instead of using HTTP GET with `_query`, you could HTTP Post the XQuery to the REST API, this would allow you to declare the namespace binding in your XQuery and use the appropriate XPath, e.g.

   ```
   declare namespace tei = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

   //tei:div/tei:p
   ```
3. Similar to (2) but you could pre-store your XQuery in the database as a file and then call the file via a HTTP GET on the REST API, which will cause XQuery to be executed.

Other options are also possible...

Comment: Thank you! Right now I just need a very simple solution with GET to test what I can get out of my documents from using _query in a browser, as that may cover my needs. I have several XQueries stored as well (solution 3), but I don't want to write lots of XQueries that I might not need.